# Laravel 4 - Composer could not load package

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

I am trying to update composer in a Laravel 4 project, but I get this error:

> [RuntimeException]   Could not load package psy/psysh in
>   http://packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse
>   version constraint ^2.4.2: Invalid version string "^2.4.2"

I haven't used `psy/psysh` within my project. Why is this returned? How can I solve this and run `composer update`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `^` character in version strings is a relatively new composer feature. Update your version of the package manager and you should be good to go

```
composer self-update
```

Comment: composer self-update throws error for me [InvalidArgumentException]             
  Command "self-update" is not defined.